# Why is my content overflowing out of div?

Tags: html, css

Here is the issue: I have a HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="fixedImg"></div>
        <div id="content" class="clearfix">
    asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />
    df<br />asdf <br />    asdf <br />

    </div>
</div>
```

And associated CSS

```
#container {
    width: 990px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top:14px;

}
#fixedImg {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url(../images/pageBg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 690px;
    border-bottom: solid #000 1px;
    background-color:#CC0000;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

But when I render it in any browser (IE, Chrome) content from 'Content' div are getting overflow.

Content div gets the height dynamically depending upon the window height (getting it correctly using JavaScript function). The text/content should be formatted with scroll bar.

---

**RESOLUTION:**

Problem was at my end inside JavaScript function, at the line where I was assigning the height to 'Content' div, I was assigning `minHeight` rather than height. corrected Line of code is given below.

```
document.getElementById('content').style.height = ht;
```

Now its working fine. I am giving the JavaScript function how to calculate screen:

```
<script language="javascript">
function getscreenInfo () {
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
    ht = y - 197;

    y += "px";
    document.getElementById('footer').style.top = y; // this will keep the 'footer' div below the visible screen. User will look at it only if he scrolls down to the bottom.
    ht += "px";
    //alert(ht);
//alert (document.getElementById('footer').style.top);
    document.getElementById('fixedImg').style.height = ht;
    document.getElementById('content').style.height = ht;

}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'Spilling Out'?

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/66d93/

Comment: Content Overflowing.... Sorry about that

Comment: Maybe its spilling out blood (pun). PS: It's fine http://jsfiddle.net/BXcmL/

Comment: What is the link from '../images/pageBg.jpg'

Comment: content div has a height depending upon the window height... text/content should be formatted with scroll bar....

Comment: pageBg.jpg is just a background image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking and we are unable to repreduce your problem.

Comment: Please, post the solution as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#container{
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Add this line, should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution of your probem:

you have to use **{height: auto;}** in div css.